# Is there a way to filter Subversion's command line merge by username

Tags: svn, version-control, branching-and-merging

I am using `svn merge urlToSomeBranch` from my working subversion copy of a freshly pulled trunk. Using the command above I can cherry pick what to merge by file or revision.  But what I would really like to do it only work on merging the changes that I made or those of another team member if needed. Is there a way to filter by username that I'm missing? I can do something similar in my IDE but alas, the one I use is hampered with a merging bug on the current release. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SVN does not supply such a feature.

I needed to do something like this recently and I ended up writing a script for that. Using SVN's XML output and PowerShell (if you're under Windows of course), it can be very simple:

```
$CmdLine = "svn log <branchURL> --stop-on-copy --xml";

$Logs = [xml](Invoke-Expression $CmdLine);

foreach ($Commit in $Logs.log.entry)
{
  $Author = $Commit.author;
  if ($Author.CompareTo("YourUsername"))
  {
    $Revision = $Commit.revision;
    $OtherCmdLine = "svn merge -r$Revision <branchURL> <target>";
    $Result = Invoke-Expression $OtherCmdLine;
  }
}
```

You could obviously do it differently but this gives the main idea.

If you're are working under a Unix based system, you can achieve the same using another scripting language.